# Fetching a row from one csv file to search for a matching row in a different csv file

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have stumbled upon a problem where i have a csv file generated with the help of CSVhelper. The file consists of 2 columns (Timestamp and ID). I would now like to open a different CSV file that contains IDs and descriptions for these IDs and import the description to the other CSVfile to match the ID with a description.

I have not however found any information on how to perform this. And wondered if there is any smooth way of performing this.

EDIT:

To clarify: I have one CSV file which contains different events which looks similar to this:

```
17/05/2022 16.28, 2 
17/05/2022 16.28, 3
```

Where the 1,2,3 and 4 represents the ID of the event that has happened. I would like to fetch a description for the ID from a different CSV file. Which looks like this:

```
1, problem 1
2, problem 2
3, problem 3
4, problem 4
```

So I would like to fetch the description for the ID 2 and 3 and insert it next to the ID so the end result would look like this:

```
17/05/2022 16.28, 2, problem 2
17/05/2022 16.28, 3, problem 3
```

Comment: Most likely yes.

Comment: ok much better now. please post the code which reads both csv files, tries to manipulate the data and writes the new resulting csv file

Comment: Read the first file into an appropriate class, read the second file into another class, join the 2 classes and select the required fields. A little bit of `linq` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Peter Smith has the right idea.  Something like this should work.

```cs
void Main()
{
    List<Foo> records;

    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false
    };

    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var options = new TypeConverterOptions { Formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy mm.ss" } };

        csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);
        
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();

        records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
    }

    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\descriptions.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var descriptions = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();

        records = records.Join(
            descriptions, 
            record => record.Id, 
            description => description.Field1, 
            (record, description) => { record.Description = description.Field2; return record; }).ToList();
    }
    
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config))
    {
        var options = new TypeConverterOptions { Formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy mm.ss" } };

        csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);
        
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap() 
    {
        Map(x => x.Id).Index(1);
        Map(x => x.Timestamp).Index(0);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    [Index(1)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Index(0)]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    [Index(2)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would I use .GroupJoin if I wanted to import more columns than only the description? Say if the file looked like this: ID, eventname, eventgroup, description

Comment: No. You would use `.GroupJoin` if there were multiple rows of each ID with say different descriptions and you wanted to add a list of descriptions to `Foo`.  You can just add the additional columns to Foo and update `Foo` with each one.  `record.EventName= description.Field2; record.EventGroup = description.Field3; record.Description = description.Field4;`